# What is the difference between "to play" or "to be playing"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

1. I need **to be playing** in Europe
2. I need **to play** in Europe

Which sentence is more correct or is there any difference at all?

Comment: What do you think? Then we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

The verb - *need* - takes a non-finite infinitive clause as its complement. By itself a non finite clause is un-tensed, therefore they can't locate a situation in time. The time they express is dictated by the verb in matrix clause. However they can express aspectuality.

Some example sentences and their meaning:

---

***N̲E̲E̲D̲ t̲o̲ b̲e̲ V̲E̲R̲B̲-̲i̲n̲g;***

---

**FUTURE**

> We really need to be doing more for our moms.

> We need to be doing this in the next 30 days.

What meaning  expressed through non-finite clause should happen in the future.

**ONGOING AT THE TIME EXPRESSED BY THE VERB OF MATRIX CLAUSE**

> We're doing what we need to be doing.

> Right now, the test is forcing us to spend too much time on stuff that we don't really need to be spending time on any more.

**HABITUAL**

> Probably not, and we probably don't need to be spending $1.5 billion every year paying for government-subsidized cell phones.

---

***N̲E̲E̲D̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲V̲E̲R̲B̲-̲pl̲a̲i̲n̲-̲f̲o̲r̲m̲***

---

**FUTURE**

> Women need to know that men and women are completely equal in the eyes of God.

> We need to take care of them before they take care of us.

---

In case of your sentences, without context they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct or incorrect the meanings are different.

---

Q1. >"I need to be playing in Europe"

A1. >means *I need to continue to play in Europe*

---

here **"be"** is an auxiliary verb used to define we are continuing to do something. In our case "playing"

Hence the meaning of the above sentence.

---

- auxiliary verb (CONTINUE) [ + -ing verb ]

  used with the present participle of other verbs to describe actions
  that are or were still continuing:

  Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be)

---

Q2. >I need to play in Europe

a2. >means I want very much to play in Europe (in the future)